# How to include special charecter in xml names using js2XmlParser?

Tags: javascript, js2xml

In the app, the table has one column named: isGlobal? and has two rows. Table data looks like this below and I would like to convert them into XML via js2xmlParser.

```
const row = [
      {
        'isGlobal?': 'no'
      },
      {
        'isGlobal?': 'yes'
      }
    ];
    const obj = {
      data: row
    }

js2xmlparser.parse('BBPXMLSchnittstelle', obj, {declaration: {encoding: 'UTF-8'}} );
```

And desired output should be :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
<data>
<isGlobal?>no</isGlobal?>
</data>
<data>
<isGlobal?>yes</isGlobal?>
</data>
</root>
```

But unfortunately as isGlobal? has a question mark I am getting an error.

```
Error: in XML document > element "root" > element "data": element name "isGlobal?" should not contain characters not allowed in XML names
```

Now how can I include this question mark or any special character in the XML names?

***Note: I cant remove the `?` mark from the data as it is collected from an HTML
table whereas one column name is `isGlobal?`. The purpose is not to change the table information, but to convert it to XML without changing it.***

Comment: What is the reason you need the `?`? The `is` prefix already indicates that the value should be a boolean

Comment: actually, my data is collected from a table, whereas the column name is isGlobal?. and i can't change the question mark as it represents a column @reyno

Comment: `?` is not a valid character in an HTML `name` attribute. Use proper variable/key names from the beginning on.